# Reformat a Large Text File in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, formatting, streamwriter

I am faced with a rather large text file (200-400 lines)

The file displays a lot of data however the problem is that it is not lined up. 
The data at the moment resembles  this

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4
Bobby      Fisher    Virginia    Rural
Willis     Johnson    Oklahoma    City
Ryan       Polk    Nevada    Suburban
Bruno      Garfield   Orgeon    Rural
```

The file uses a set number of spaces between each entry, which causes the problem.
Is there a way to possible break this up and for each word allow X amount of spaces, and if it is shorter fill in the space with spaces?

My only thought at the moment would be to pull each line from the text file and then pull each word.

Is there an easier way or am I just in a pretty big pickle?

Most of you all can guess what the end product will look like but here it is

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4
Bobby      Fisher     Virginia   Rural
Willis     Johnson    Oklahoma   City
Ryan       Polk       Nevada     Suburban
Bruno      Garfield   Orgeon     Rural
```

Comment: "I am faced with a rather large text file (200-400 lines)" *laughs*

Comment: You get a +1 for making me feel dumb haha. True, BUTTT it looks like 20000 - 40000 then it zig zags all the way down the file :)

Comment: lol, wasn't trying to make you feel dumb, haha. It's just that I was looking at a 600-lined file that contained my history class notes for a semester, so it was kinda funny to see you say that. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
Array.ConvertAll(lines, _
    Function(cells) _
        String.Concat( _
            Array.ConvertAll(cells.Split(), Function(s) s.Trim().PadRight(40))))
```